# Can the Paypal payment link be modified to bypass login and go directly to guest checkout?

Tags: paypal, payment

Paypal are giving us the URL for the customer checkout for a given product/service.
It asks for the user to login first but we need the link to go directly to the guest page.

Example URL : https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=CZNFQHFPHJDM8

Can this URL be modified to bypass and go directly to guest checkout?

Thanks

Comment: To my knowledge not legally (in the US and EU) no and also why on earth would you do that.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change the behavior of the PayPal page. But you can instead create a smart button via https://www.paypal.com/buttons/smart , which will have a black "Debit or Credit Card" option for guests.

It's highly configurable, for example with the [disable-funding parameter](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/javascript-sdk/javascript-sdk-configuration/#disable-funding) if there are any buttons you don't want.

More information at [Set up standard payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/)